Displaying HTML text in SwiftUI causing attribute cycles or crashes
I need to be able to display HTML tagged text with a SwiftUI text view.
Following tutorials I came to this UIViewRepresentable solution using NSAttributedString.
struct HTMLText: UIViewRepresentable {
    var attributedText: NSAttributedString

    init(text: String) {
        self.attributedText = text.htmlToAttributedString
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let uiTextView = UITextView()

        uiTextView.backgroundColor = .red
        uiTextView.textContainerInset = .zero
        uiTextView.isEditable = false
        uiTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

        return uiTextView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiTextView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiTextView.attributedText = attributedText
    }

}

extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else {
            return NSAttributedString(string: self) }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(
                data: data,
                options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                          .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString(string: self)
        }
    }
}

While this works nicely for simple views, I have run into difficulty incorporating it into my app. Something to do with a NavigationStack causes cycles in the attribute graph: === AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 96280 ===. Used in my app a few dozen of these messages are logged and no text field displayed. More fatally, GeometryReader used directly as a parent view seems to cause a SIGABRT, with a logging of precondition failure: setting value during update: 768.
This replication causes cycles, although only a few and the text is displayed:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button(action: {
                showView.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Show view")
            })
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showView, destination: {
                ScrollableView()  // Putting the scroll view here directly seems to be fine
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollableView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HTMLText(text: "hello <em> world </em>")
        }
    }
}

And this causes a complete crash.
struct Crash: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { _ in
            HTMLText(text: "hello <em> world </em>")
        }
    }
}

The exact point where things go wrong is where the string data is attempted to be coded into the attributed string, even though it is wrapped in a try block, the error does not seem to be handled here at all. I've not been able to find other ways to display HTML text, do I have other options? What steps can I take to try debug an attribute graph?

As debug your code, I found out that when access htmlToAttributedString, you can see an internal function _UIHostingView.requestImmediateUpdate call. Base on its name, I think its job is to force UI reload immediately. Which will cause a cycle as show with this logging AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute. As you can see when put debug breakpoint in init of HTMLText:

A ScrollableView.body.getter will lead to another ScrollableView.body.getter.

To get rid of this problem, my suggestion is to put your htmlToAttributedString in a DispatchQueue.main.async:
struct HTMLText: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text // instead of create NSAttributedString, just save a String
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let uiTextView = UITextView()

        uiTextView.backgroundColor = .red
        uiTextView.textContainerInset = .zero
        uiTextView.isEditable = false
        uiTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

        return uiTextView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiTextView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //<- get rid of cycle
            uiTextView.attributedText = self.text.htmlToAttributedString
        }
    }
}


Amazing, thank you!

out of curiosity, how does this prevent a cycle? Im aware that your change has put the attribute string creation on the main queue to be done asynchronously, where was it before? And was the problem that it was originally scheduled synchronously?

For first question, answer is yes, before attribute string creation is on main thread, as we are interact with UI component ( UITextView ). For second question, answer is yes too, you can see in my image of the stacktrace when I run original code, they are of the same stacktrace
